# does ndb have a list property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, list, google-cloud-datastore

Instead of a single StringProperty(),
I want to store a list of strings

```
class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
    s1 = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    s2 = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    s3 = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

I would rather go

```
class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
    my_strings = ndb.StringListProperty() # does this exist?
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

yes, use a repeated property:

> Any property with repeated=True becomes a repeated property. The
>   property takes a list of values of the underlying type, rather than a
>   single value. For example, the value of a property defined with
>   IntegerProperty(repeated=True) is a list of integers.

see the docs: [Repeated Properties](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#repeated)

Comment: note it's up to the programmer to ensure the length of the list is 3 (if you only wanted a list of length 3 say)

Answer (score 6):

Also if you are only operating on lists and you don't need indexing you can use the `ndb.JsonProperty` that will parse a list with non empty **valid** Json objects. By this way you **can also compress** your data but you lose indexing if you don't enable it as arg, because it is stored as a Blob.